# Expression in java to format Double value into specific decimal point

Tags: java, double, expression, decimalformat

I have a series of data like so:
100 Mbps,
200 Mbps,
512 Kbps,
256 Kbps,
100 Mbps,

I need to standardize all the data which all must be in the 'Mbps' unit. i am using an ETL software from Jaspersoft which allow expression to be entered to transform the data. Each data will be splitted into 2 variable which is one to store the unit(speedunit) and another one to store the value(speedvalue) which is type Double. Right now im using the following expression:

```
speedunit.equalsIgnoreCase("Kbps") ? (speedvalue / 1000) : speedunit.equalsIgnoreCase("Gbps") ? (speedvalue * 1000) : Var.speedvalue
```

The problem is, it round up the value to integer. 
eg. 512 suppose to be 0.512 but 1 is displayed instead. Math.round doesn't help either. I cannot put in any user-defined function. Only expression is allowed. So it must be a one-liner expression like in the example

The formatted value will then be saved to a MSSQL table in column which were given the type 'decimal(28, 2)'

**Update:**
Tried this but didn't work either

```
speedunit.equalsIgnoreCase("kbps") ? Mathematical.REAL(String.valueOf(speedvalue/1000))
```

This gives error "DecimalFormat cannot be resolved to a type"

```
speedunit.equalsIgnoreCase("kbps") ? new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(String.valueOf(speedvalue / 1000)))
```

Comment: import java.text.DecimalFormat will resolve the error that decimalformat cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: thats help resolved the error. thank you very much. but still the output is not in decimal

Answer (score 0):

You can use type casting to double here. So your expression can be like this

```java
speedunit.equalsIgnoreCase("Kbps") ? 
    (double)(speedvalue / 1000) 
    : speedunit.equalsIgnoreCase("Gbps") ? (double)(speedvalue * 1000) 
    : speedvalue
```

Evaluation of `10/100` would give you `0` where as evaluation of `(double)10/100` would give you `0.1`

If you want to limit your decimals to specific number of digits, you can use the expression as below (limiting to two decimals)

```java
speedunit.equalsIgnoreCase("Kbps") ? 
    (double)Math.round(100*((double)(speedvalue / 1000))/100 
    : speedunit.equalsIgnoreCase("Gbps") ? 
    (double)Math.round(100*((double)(speedvalue * 1000))/100 
    : speedvalue
```

If you want to limit to three decimals, change `100` to `1000`. Using `java.text.DecimalFormat` is a better way to format numbers. Using multiply and divide with `Math.round()` is a solution where such libraries are not available.

If you can use `DecimalFormat`, then your optimal solution would be

```java
speedunit.equalsIgnoreCase("Kbps") ? 
    new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(String.valueOf((double)(speedvalue / 1000))/100 
    : speedunit.equalsIgnoreCase("Gbps") ? 
    new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(String.valueOf((double)(speedvalue * 1000))/100 
    : speedvalue
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [demo](http://goo.gl/7nJPXz) for you:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class DecimalFormatDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String speedunit = "Kbps";
        double speedvalue = 512;
        double result = 
                speedunit.equalsIgnoreCase("Kbps") ? (speedvalue / 1000) : speedunit.equalsIgnoreCase("Gbps") ? (speedvalue * 1000) : speedvalue;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
        System.out.println(df.format(result));

    }
}
```

**Note:**

Since speedvalue is of type **"double"** assigning the result to a variable of type **double** would suffice. 
Then you are just required to format the result to your desired decimal format.

Comment: This is almost the same as my last update. i have resolved the error by using this 'speedunit.equalsIgnoreCase("kbps") ? Double.parseDouble(new java.text.DecimalFormat("0.00").format(speedvalue/1000))' but still not the right output

Comment: maybe i should include that the formatted value will then be saved to MSSQL database in a column which have 'decimal' type

Comment: I've added a demo. Please go to the above link. You may have a look at the result it generates.